# Awareness on X vs. awareness of X

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-choice

Example, should one say "awareness on depression" or awareness of depression"?

I'm confused because I found both usages.

Example:

> We'll also be hosting an event raising **awareness on depression** and
>   substance abuse

[Source.](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=_ev3empq26gC&q=%22Awareness%20on%20depression%22&dq=%22Awareness%20on%20depression%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT2-3vo8znAhUKrJQKHbiUA0oQ6AEISTAE)

> Public health measures have included campaigns to raise **awareness of
>   depression** both in the general public and in healthcare providers.

[Source.](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=gP1sAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA675&dq=%22Awareness%20of%20depression%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvru-xpMznAhVpzIsBHT-iDVM4FBDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=%22Awareness%20of%20depression%22&f=false)

Are both phrases valid? Or they mean different things?

My own sentence:

> Despite their efforts, awareness on/of depression didn't increase at
>   all in  their area.

Comment: Despite their efforts, awareness **on** depression didn't improve in their area at all.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510281/awareness-on-vs-awareness-of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you raise awareness *of* something, not *on* something. The first sentence that uses *on* does so because of the way it references the event. They are holding an event that raises awareness. That event is on [the topic of] depression and substance abuse. They aren't raising awareness "on depression", they are holding an event on depression that raises awareness (although the meaning is effectively the same). The sentence could have been rewritten as:

> We'll also be hosting an event raising awareness of depression and
>   substance abuse.

This sentence has essentially the same meaning, and I'd argue that this version is somewhat more easily parsed, as it doesn't have the somewhat unusual appearance of "awareness on".

Comment: I mostly agree with this answer but I think the usage is a little more complex, although I'm having trouble identifying exactly what is going on. I found a headline "Morning Consult editor says there is a lack of awareness on early voting". It seems like there are two senses in which "awareness" can be used: most commonly as simply being aware of something, or more abstractly as a kind of presence in public discourse. It's the latter where "on" is apparently sometimes used. I would advise ELLs not to use "on" since "of" always works and "on" could easily be used incorrectly.